# Как отобразить картинку на форме в Qt?

Tags: qt

Не минусуйте за простой вопрос, плиз. Просто я новичок в Qt и сходу не могу найти элемент управления, который бы просто отображал картинку на форме.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
QPixmap myPixmap( "image.png" );

label->setPixmap( myPixmap );
```

Вот так вроде. Ну, разумеется, label тоже создать.

Answer (score 1):

С помощью метки (QLabel). Вот [ссылка](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#pixmap-prop) на документацию.

Comment: поменял на рабочую

Answer (score 0):

ну или можно самому рисовать в QPainter'е окна. все зависит от того в каких целях вам надо вывести изображение..